# PHP previous and next for different URL's

Tags: php

Hi i have 5 different url, i need to show this url in previous and next using array..

Url are differents if i visit any url i need to go next are previous. How can i do this using PHP.

```
$images = array(

'1' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/glass/13/',

'2' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/choose-your/10/',

'3' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/a-room-is-not/9/',

'4' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/rated/13/',

'5' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/a-room-is-natural-light/9/' );
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Show us what you have tried? where and how exactly you are using or visiting the URLs?

Comment: elaborate your question...... do you want to show it as pagination ?

Comment: Yes i have tried..

Comment: $key = $_GET['key'];

$next = $key + 1;

$prev = $key - 1;

?>

<?php if ($prev >= 0): ?>

   <a href="<?php echo "http://localhost/technical-articles?key=".$prev;?>">Previous</a>

      
<?php endif; ?>

 
<?php if ($next < count($images)): ?> 

<a href="<?php echo "http://localhost/technical-articles?key=".$next;?>">Next</a>

 
 <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Yes i need this to be a pagination like previous and next button..

Comment: please add new question information directly into the question via an edit

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
$currentPage = array_search($currentPage, $images);

$previousPage = $currentPage - 1;
$nextPage = $currentPage + 1;
```

And this is how you'd display it on your HTML:

```
<?php if ($previousPage >= 0): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $images[$prev] ?>">Previous</a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($nextPage < count($images)): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $images[$next] ?>">Next</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get that by this way. first check the current page url in the array of pages and find next and previous pages . Try below codes

```
     $images = array(
            '1' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/glass/13/',
            '2' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/choose-your/10/',
            '3' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/a-room-is-not/9/',
            '4' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/rated/13/',
            '5' => 'http://localhost/technical-articles/a-room-is-natural-light/9/' );

        $currentPage = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $currentPageNo = array_search($currentPage,$images);
        $nextPage = isset($images[$currentPageNo+1]) ? $images[$currentPageNo+1] : '';
        $prePage = isset($images[$currentPageNo-1]) ? $images[$currentPageNo-1] : '';
        echo $currentPageNo.'<br>'.$nextPage.'<br>'.$prePage);
```

Comment: Hi Shams this shows current URL but didn't show previous and next

Comment: are you getting `$currentPageNo` ?

Comment: if you are getting `$currentPageNo` then you must get `$nextPage` and `$prePage` or any one of them according the current page position . suppose if you are at first page then $prePage is empty.

Comment: Thank u guyz now its working fine..  @ Shams also i'm getting page no..